# What do I do when I get a Linux kernel bug?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel-panic, fit-pc

I just bought a tiny computer called a fit-pc2 which came with a somewhat customized Ubuntu 9.10 installation. uname -a reports:

```
Linux 2.6.31-34-fitpc2 #7 SMP Thu Apr 22 17:43:26 IDT 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

It seems that after several hours of running with heavy network load, all networking ceases and I get the following in kern.log:

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ff09dfc0
IP: [<c0150300>] kthread_should_stop+0x10/0x20
*pde = 00000000 
Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/idVendor
Modules linked in: binfmt_misc ppdev sbc_fitpc2_wdt snd_usb_audio snd_usb_lib i2c_isch sch_gpio snd_seq_dummy snd_hda_intel snd_pcm_oss snd_seq_oss snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi snd_mixer_oss snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_pcm snd_timer snd_page_alloc snd_seq_device iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables snd_hwdep lpc_sch snd psmouse rt2860sta(C) uvcvideo video pl2303 soundcore mfd_core output videodev v4l1_compat lirc_igorplugusb lirc_dev serio_raw lp parport usbhid r8169 mii iegd_mod drm agpgart

Pid: 16, comm: kblockd/1 Tainted: G         C (2.6.31-34-fitpc2 #7) SBC-FITPC2
EIP: 0060:[<c0150300>] EFLAGS: 00010246 CPU: 1
EIP is at kthread_should_stop+0x10/0x20
EAX: ff09dfc4 EBX: c180cbac ECX: 0109d000 EDX: f709df98
ESI: f709df98 EDI: c180cba0 EBP: f709dfb8 ESP: f709df90
 DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 0000 SS: 0068
Process kblockd/1 (pid: 16, ti=f709c000 task=f7084b60 task.ti=f709c000)
Stack:
 c014c14d c180cba4 00000000 f7084b60 c0150770 f709dfa4 f709dfa4 f7023ef4
<0> c180cba0 c014c0d0 f709dfe0 c015047c 00000000 00000000 00000000 f709dfcc
<0> f709dfcc c0150400 00000000 00000000 00000000 c0103ce7 f7023ef4 00000000
Call Trace:
 [<c014c14d>] ? worker_thread+0x7d/0xe0
 [<c0150770>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<c014c0d0>] ? worker_thread+0x0/0xe0
 [<c015047c>] ? kthread+0x7c/0x90
 [<c0150400>] ? kthread+0x0/0x90
 [<c0103ce7>] ? kernel_thread_helper+0x7/0x10
Code: a6 8b 55 0c 8d 4d e0 89 f8 89 34 24 e8 7a fd ff ff 89 c3 eb 92 90 90 90 90 90 90 55 64 a1 00 80 76 c0 8b 80 70 02 00 00 89 e5 5d <8b> 40 fc c3 8d b6 00 00 00 00 8d bf 00 00 00 00 55 ba d7 86 62 
EIP: [<c0150300>] kthread_should_stop+0x10/0x20 SS:ESP 0068:f709df90
CR2: 00000000ff09dfc0
---[ end trace 06004df70b9cf435 ]---
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ff09dfc8
IP: [<c0521bc8>] _spin_lock_irqsave+0x18/0x30
*pde = 00000000 
Oops: 0002 [#2] SMP 
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/idVendor
Modules linked in: binfmt_misc ppdev sbc_fitpc2_wdt snd_usb_audio snd_usb_lib i2c_isch sch_gpio snd_seq_dummy snd_hda_intel snd_pcm_oss snd_seq_oss snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi snd_mixer_oss snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_pcm snd_timer snd_page_alloc snd_seq_device iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables snd_hwdep lpc_sch snd psmouse rt2860sta(C) uvcvideo video pl2303 soundcore mfd_core output videodev v4l1_compat lirc_igorplugusb lirc_dev serio_raw lp parport usbhid r8169 mii iegd_mod drm agpgart

Pid: 16, comm: kblockd/1 Tainted: G      D  C (2.6.31-34-fitpc2 #7) SBC-FITPC2
EIP: 0060:[<c0521bc8>] EFLAGS: 00010086 CPU: 1
EIP is at _spin_lock_irqsave+0x18/0x30
EAX: 00000100 EBX: ff09dfc8 ECX: 00000286 EDX: ff09dfc8
ESI: f7084b60 EDI: ff09dfc4 EBP: f709dd88 ESP: f709dd88
 DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 0000 SS: 0068
Process kblockd/1 (pid: 16, ti=f709c000 task=f7084b60 task.ti=f709c000)
Stack:
 f709dda4 c0127c0b 00000082 00000001 ff09dfc4 f7084b60 00000000 f709ddd0
<0> c0137fd2 00000086 f70954c4 00000000 f7098480 f709ddf0 f7094fc0 f7084b60
<0> 00000000 00000009 f709ddf0 c013c3f8 00000001 c1807c60 f709ddf0 f7084b60
Call Trace:
 [<c0127c0b>] ? complete+0x1b/0x60
 [<c0137fd2>] ? mm_release+0x52/0xf0
 [<c013c3f8>] ? exit_mm+0x18/0x110
 [<c013c6db>] ? do_exit+0xfb/0x2e0
 [<c013998a>] ? print_oops_end_marker+0x2a/0x30
 [<c0522aab>] ? oops_end+0x8b/0xd0
 [<c011eac4>] ? no_context+0xb4/0xd0
 [<c011eb1d>] ? __bad_area_nosemaphore+0x3d/0x1a0
 [<c0133a56>] ? load_balance_newidle+0x96/0x320
 [<c011ec92>] ? bad_area_nosemaphore+0x12/0x20
 [<c0524106>] ? do_page_fault+0x2f6/0x380
 [<c012cc30>] ? finish_task_switch+0x50/0xe0
 [<c0523e10>] ? do_page_fault+0x0/0x380
 [<c0522006>] ? error_code+0x66/0x70
 [<c0523e10>] ? do_page_fault+0x0/0x380
 [<c0150300>] ? kthread_should_stop+0x10/0x20
 [<c014c14d>] ? worker_thread+0x7d/0xe0
 [<c0150770>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
 [<c014c0d0>] ? worker_thread+0x0/0xe0
 [<c015047c>] ? kthread+0x7c/0x90
 [<c0150400>] ? kthread+0x0/0x90
 [<c0103ce7>] ? kernel_thread_helper+0x7/0x10
Code: 00 00 00 55 89 e5 f0 83 28 01 79 05 e8 02 ff ff ff 5d c3 55 89 c2 89 e5 9c 58 8d 74 26 00 89 c1 fa 90 8d 74 26 00 b8 00 01 00 00 <f0> 66 0f c1 02 38 e0 74 06 f3 90 8a 02 eb f6 89 c8 5d c3 90 8d 
EIP: [<c0521bc8>] _spin_lock_irqsave+0x18/0x30 SS:ESP 0068:f709dd88
CR2: 00000000ff09dfc8
---[ end trace 06004df70b9cf436 ]---
Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
```

This seems to happen at least once a day. How do I even begin to debug this?

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/KernelTeamBugPolicies and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelOops may get you some help

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same problem when I recompiled the Lenny stock kernel with Atom CPU and RTL8168c/8111c NIC enabled.

After reverting to the "ubuntu" kernel provided by Compulab, the kernel messages went away.
However, the NIC is still dropping connection when the link is under moderate load which is a real PITA for headless servers, which after all these boxes are designed for!

I would advice anyone planning to run Linux on these boxes to **look else where**, since these boxes are very **unstable on Linux**. Better to buy some standard mini-atx setup since Compulab seems as interested in supporting Linux as ATI or FireDTV have been the past decade.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you have narrowed it down to heavy networking use, so I would say, look for a different/better/newer network driver as the problem most likely lies there.

If you can't, I would go in to the BIOS and disable the network interface (if it is built in) and buy yourself a bog standard non Realtek card then see if you have better luck with that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you paid money for a computer that comes with a custom Linux distribution installed, bug the vendor. I believe it's their job to handle it or pass the bug report upstream.

If you're on your own, it's a different story. You have many choices: change hardware, try building another kernel version, try debugging the issue yourself if you are skilled enough.